# Audio Overlapping

Tags: android, media-player

Playmusic and Playmusic1 get overlapping. so i paused both mediaplayers. but while restarting mediaplayers either get playing from where i paused. but i want both player should start from beginning?
help in fix this issue.
        public void initPlayMusic(Context context, int count) {
        playMusic = MediaPlayer.create(context, count);
        playMusic.setVolume(100, 100);
        playMusic.setLooping(false);
        }
        public void playMusic() {
        playMusic.start();
        Log.i("start", "long Music");
        }
        public void stopMusic()
        {
        if(playMusic!=null)
        {
         playMusic.stop();
         playMusic.release();
         playMusic=null;
        }

```
   }
   public void pauseMusic()
    {
    if(playMusic.isPlaying() && playMusic!=null)
    {
       playMusic.pause();
       Log.i("pause", "Long Music pause");
     }
     }
    public MediaPlayer getPlayMusic()
    {
    return playMusic;
    }
   public void initPlayMusic1(Context context, int count)
   {
    playMusic1 = MediaPlayer.create(context, count);
    playMusic1.setVolume(100, 100);
    playMusic1.setLooping(false);
    }
    public void playMusic1(){
     playMusic1.start();
    Log.i("start", "short Music");
      }
    public void stopMusic1()
    {
    if(playMusic1!=null)
    {
    playMusic1.stop();
    playMusic1.release();
    playMusic1=null;
    }
    }
   public void pauseMusic1()
   {
    if(playMusic1.isPlaying() && playMusic1!=null)
    {
     playMusic1.pause();
     Log.i("pause", "short Music pause");
     playMusic1.seekTo(0);
     }
    }
    public MediaPlayer getPlayMusic1()
    {
     return playMusic1;
    }
```